# parse CSV file and compare line by line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm beginer in Python coding,

I try to open a CSV file and compare line by line,

Now I compare line 1 and line 2, then line 3 and line 4,

I want to compare line 1 and line 2, then line 2 and line 3, then line 3 and line 4,

My code :

```
    with open('file.csv', newline='') as f:
          reader0 = csv.reader(f)
          rownum = 0
          for row in reader0:
                 try:
                     miaw = next(reader0)
                     OTIME = row[27]
                     NOTIME = miaw[27]
                     if rownum == 0:
                        header = row
                        rownum += 1
                     else:
                        print(row[0],row[1],OTIME,miaw[0],miaw[1],NOTIME)
                  except:
                  print ("exception")
```

This give me the results :

```
1 ID1 05-APR-12 00.00.05.800000 2 ID2 05-APR-12 00.00.05.801000
3 ID3 05-APR-12 00.00.06.074000 4 ID4 05-APR-12 00.00.13.003000
```

My aim is to compare timestamps,

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you call `next(reader0)`, the second line is only read once when the first line is compared against it.

Use a buffer for the previous line outside the `for` loop.

```
last_line = None
for row in reader0:
    if last_line is None:
        last_line = row
        continue

    # now compare row to last_line

    last_line = row
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the timestamps for all your lines and do whatever you like with them ( *you didn't specify what kind of comparison is done*), and this can be done with regex like this example:

```
data = "1 ID1 05-APR-12 00.00.05.800000 2 ID2 05-APR-12 00.00.05.801000 3 ID3 05-APR-12 00.00.06.074000 4 ID4 05-APR-12 00.00.13.003000"

import re
timestamps = re.findall(r'\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{6}', data)
print timestamps
```

and the result will come in this case as:

```
['00.00.05.800000', '00.00.05.801000', '00.00.06.074000', '00.00.13.003000']
```

hope this helps.